# Slick silently fails to save and doesn't' throw an exception

Tags: scala, slick

I just ran into a very scary situation with slick.  My table definition referred to a wrong column and I noticed that the inserts where not inserting yet there was no error/exception about the issue.  It just "silently" failed.

Is this normal slick behaviour?

So my table definition was like:

```
  def expiredAt = column[Timestamp]["created_at"]
  def createdAt = column[Timestamp]["created_at"]
```

As you can see, the column referenced for both is the same column "created_at".  When I changed the expiredAt column to "expired_at" everything worked fine.

But the really issue for me is that there was no exception thrown at all.

Is this normal slick behaviour?  What is going on under the covers?  Does it not return 0 for updatedRows?

My save method looks like:

```
(users returning users.map(_.id)) += user
```

I am using slick3.

Comment: Don't know about Slick, but i've seen bonecp (default with play <2.4) swallow exceptions. What db connection pool are you using?

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco I am using bonecp at the moment, with play 2.3.10.

Comment: Yeah, had the same issue, wasted hours trying to find the problem. Stopped happening when I switched to HikariCP. Upgrade to play 2.4 if you can (uses hikaricp by default). If you're stuck on 2.3, you'll have to use the hikaricp play plugin.

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco appreciate it, why not put that in an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Are you examining the results of the `Future` that `db.run` returns? Unless you're dereferencing the `Future` at some point (via `map` or `Await` or whatever), the exception will sit silently inside it.

Comment: @Blankman Wasn't sure if it was it or not. Moved it to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, solved it with recover:

```
val query = (users returning earningsForms.map(_.id) += user
db.run(query).recover{ ex: Throwable => Logger.error("Error occured when inserting user", ex)}
```

Comment: But I am not even seeing an exception.  You mean the exception is swallowed unless I add .recover?

Comment: The exception isn't being swallowed; it's being recorded in the `Future` that's returned by `db.run`. You need to retrieve the result of the `Future` in order to gauge success or failure.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Slick, but i've seen bonecp (default with play <2.4) swallow exceptions under certain conditions.

I had the same issue, wasted hours trying to find the problem. Stopped happening when I switched to HikariCP. Upgrade to play 2.4 if you can (uses hikaricp by default). If you're stuck on 2.3, you'll have to use the hikaricp play plugin.