# Slick mapper fails, but didnt' see any exception

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

In slick I have a column mapper that maps an enumeration.

The database had a integer value that wasn't in my enumeration (int value 2), and I didn't see any exception in my logs.

Why isn't there an error thrown?  I had a for-compr that just never completed in my code.

```
object MemberStatus extends Enumeration {
  type MemberStatus = Value
  val Pending, Active = Value  // it was missing a new value HERE!!!
}
```

In my slick table I have this:

```
implicit lazy val memberStatus = MappedColumnType.base[MemberStatus, Int](
      ms => md.id,
      i => MemberStatus(i)
    )
```

I have been trying to debug this for a while, and I just realized that my database row had the value 2 for member_status.

When I updated my enum to:

```
object MemberStatus extends Enumeration {
  type MemberStatus = Value
  val Pending, Active, Deleted = Value
}
```

It works fine.

I added this to my logback.xml also:

```
<logger name="slick.jdbc" level="DEBUG"/>
```

Why isn't there an exception thrown?  Or if there is, why didn't I see it?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it simply about using `recover` / `recoverWith` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34588733/2239369 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42254112/2239369 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41875646/2239369 ?

Comment: So in your code, you have recover/recoverWith in all your db calls in slick?  I don't see examples of that, but it seems it should be a best practise then correct?